# Display Double as string ignoring decimal part when the value is a whole number

Tags: java

What's the simplest way to display a `double` as `String` but not showing the decimal part if the `double` value is a whole number?

For example, 
If I have the `double` value **10.0** it would display only **10** (no decimal part), but if I have the `double` value **10.35** it would display the complete value **10.35**.

Comment: simplest? maybe `Double.toString(var).repalceAll("\\.0$","")`

Comment: I wouldn't like to use regex for this.

Comment: than it is not simplest.... and not requested... but `if ( str.endsWith(".0") ) return str.substring(0, str.length()-2)` or so

Comment: Simplest also in terms of performance.

Comment: 'also" is a contradiction, you must be more specific, but see previous comment... not that simple anymore IMO

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Last answer is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double one = 1.00;
String stringNumber;
if (one % 1 == 0) {
    Integer intOne = (int) one;
    stringNumber = intOne.toString();
} else {
    stringNumber = String.valueOf(one);
}
```

Comment: This is actually better:

                        stringNumber = one % 1 == 0 ? String.valueOf((int) one) : String.valueOf(one);

Answer (score 3):

I would use this approach:

```
// 1. Make sure to have dot instead of comma as a separator:
DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
// 2. Define max number of decimal places:
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###", symbol);

// 3. Use it:
System.out.println(df.format(yourNumber));
```

Comment: Good solution too. I don't like a bit to use formats, but it's better than regex.

Comment: @Marcos Why not?  This is exactly what NumberFormats are for.

Comment: @VGR Because although NumberFormats are used for this, they're slower compared to 'Daisy Day' solution, which is also a simple solution like NumberFormat.

Comment: @Marcos Slower by how much?  A few nanoseconds?  Did you measure it?  Does the difference matter?  Writing clear, obvious code is a much more useful skill than saving a few CPU cycles, unless you’re doing embedded programming.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [java.text.NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Example:

```
    final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format( 10.0d ));
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format( 10.35d ));
```

the output will be:

> 10
>
> 10,35

Comment: that's a nice one!  and it uses the Locale!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
System.out.println(getString(4.53)); // 4.53
System.out.println(getString(4.0)); // 4

public String getString(double d){
    return (d % 1 == 0) ? String.valueOf((int) d) : String.valueOf(d);
}
```